# Is there a logical (boolean) XOR function in C or C++ standard library?

Tags: c++, xor

I didn't find one, but have a hard time believing there is none.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Boolean XOR is the same thing as `!=`, "not equal."

```
p | q | p != q
--+---+-------
F | F |   F    
T | F |   T    
F | T |   T    
T | T |   F
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_conjunction

Comment: I disagree. The expression `1!=2` evaluates to `true`, but `1 XOR 2` is very definitely false, since both 1 and 2 are `true`. To use the != operator as an XOR, you must cast to `bool` first.

Comment: @quinxorin: that's nonsense. I asked about _logical_ XOR, 1 and 2 aren't _logical_ values. In C++, logical means `bool`.

Comment: I appear to have misunderstood your question. I didn't realize by "logical XOR" you meant that the values were already boolean.

Comment: I agree with @IanPudney. If you know both values are exactly either 0 or 1 (i.e. logical), then why not just use the `^` bitwise XOR operator? Using either `^` or `!=` will return incorrect results under the same conditions (when the values are not both exactly either 0 or 1).

Comment: ^ is an operation on integral values not logical values. 0 ^ 1 returns an int which is fine but so does true ^ false which can cause problems. ( true ^ false ) == true may give a compiler warning/error about comparing an int with a bool. This is why there is an & distinct from &&. For consistency there should be a ^^

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for whether two values are identical, you can use `!=` or the bitwise operator `^`. You can use this if your values are already `bool`. However, if your values are not purely `bool`, cast them to `bool` first:

```
((bool)myVal)!=((bool)myOtherVal)
((bool)myVal)^((bool)myOtherVal)
//either works
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the second works? Does the standard say all `bool` variables that evaluate to the same value are bitwise equal?

Comment: I am unsure about the standard; it works in MinGW on Windows.

Comment: That doesn't mean anything at all.

Comment: Using ^ on booleans converts them to integers, and yes, the standard says that true converts to 1. It's in 4.5/6.